# ParseQuery WhereKey:MatchesQuery equivalent for .NET

Tags: c#, .net, swift, parse-platform

Is there any way to implement the following Swift code in .NET? The method seems to be missing in the .NET Parse SDK
(I have a one to many relationship linking the event object to the code object)

```
let query = PFQuery(className: "Events")
let innerQuery = PFQuery(className: "Codes")
innerQuery.whereKey("status", equalTo:"red")
query.whereKey("code",  matchesQuery:innerQuery)
```

Answer (score 0):

Seems it was slightly renamed:

```
        var innerQuery = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Codes")
            .WhereEqualTo ("status", "red");
        var query = ParseObject.GetQuery ("Events")
            .WhereMatchesQuery ("code", innerQuery);
        IEnumerable<ParseObject> results = await query.FindAsync();
```